# Using filter() Method with Arrow-Function Arguments

Tags: javascript, filter, arrow-functions

I've understood how to use `filter`, but seeing this answer to this exercise: [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.4) confuses me (you can see the code when you click 'look at the solution'. Just what is the difference between:

```
let counted = countBy(text, char => {
  let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
  return script ? script.direction : "none";
}).filter(({name}) => name != "none");
```

and:

```
let counted = countBy(text, char => {
    let script = characterScript(char.codePointAt(0));
    return script ? script.direction : "none";
}).filter(name => name != "none"); //The difference is here and when I tried this, it did not work
```

What I'm familiar with is using `... .filter(something => condition);` and it will return an array of all the items from the original array that fulfills said condition. I tried changing the above code to `... .filter(script => script.name != "none")` and it worked. So what exactly does `({name})` do so specially that I don't have to type that long?

Comment: it looks like destructuring. but I'm not sure `{name} => name` is valid or not.

Comment: I thought object destructuring had to be wrapped in brackets when used in an arrow function argument.

Comment: @CameronMartin I've fixed the code. It didn't work if it doesn't have braces, is that just the rule to using object destructuring in an arrow function argument?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer I _think_ the only time the parentheses can be omitted is when the parameter is just an identifier. So you need parentheses when using array destructuring, object destructuring and default parameters.

Comment: @CameronMartin I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's object destructuring in action. Instead of passing an object `x` into the filter and then comparing to `x.name`, you're just destructuring `name` right out.

`.filter(({name}) => name != "none");`

is equivalent to

`.filter(x => x.name != "none");`

More on destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: I see, thank you! I've forgotten Object Destructuring I've learnt before in the books, I'll read again.